# Saving json in table storage

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have read some articles around this subject. Most stating if you want to save json in table storage your object need to inherit from TableEntity and cannot be complex. Is there a problem just saving it in a string column and deserialize yourself?

Comment: can you explain more? it's not very clear.

Comment: Yes. I dont want by classes to inherit from TableEntity. So my question is there any limitations, performance or constraints if added a string column and just saved the json as a string in that specific column. Not as suggested @ivan yang below. Maybe string columns as a limited length, or somethink like that. Or is the only recommended way the suggestion in Ivan Yangs answer. The thing is I dont like being bound to my model  have to derive from TableEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

> "Is there a problem just saving it in a string column and deserialize
>   yourself?"

If you mean save the json string as a string column, and then desirialize it by yourself, then the answer is yes, you can do that, no problem. Remember you should define partition key and row key for the record.

A sample code that defines the entity like below, for more details you can refer to the [table storage samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#define-the-entity):

```
    public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
    {
        //the parameter-less constructor is a must.
        public CustomerEntity()
        {
        }

        public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
        {
            PartitionKey = lastName;
            RowKey = firstName;
        }

        public string myJson { get; set; }
    }
```

After define the entity, you can use insert / retrieve etc. method for your need, and deserialize the json data by your own code.

Comment: Thanks @ivan yang. Your sample is exactly what I try to avoid :D I dont want my classes to inherit from TableEntity. So the question is, is there any pittfalls if you just used NewtonsSoft to parse the object to a string. And added that to a column of type string. Why are we deriving from TableEntity what does it actually give us? Is it because string columns are limited in size or what is the reason for this?

Comment: You can see in the documentation: "Edm.String String A UTF-16-encoded value. String values may be up to 64 KB in size. Note that the maximum number of characters supported is about 32 K or less". Will using your sample change that constraint?

Comment: @ThomasSegato You cannot change the constraint of size with/without using TableEntity. If you don't want to have a class derived from Table Entity, you can use DynamicTableEntity(which is actually a derived class from ITableEntity) to insert data into azure table, follow this [doc](https://amithegde.com/2015/02/writing-dynamictableentity-to-azure-storage-table.html) to do that. For why we need a class derived from ITableEntity, because in .net, the insert method only accepts the item which is a ITableEntity.